# Running node.js on a bluemix node.js app

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

I'm very new to Bluemix and node.js. I have a node.js application that I want to run in Bluemix but I'm not sure how to actually run node.js on it. When I tried opening the site on bluemix my javascript file had the error that the require function wasn't defined, meaning that node.js wasn't running.  Am I supposed to change something in the package.json file to allow a specific javascript file to run node.js or what? Sorry for being so clueless.

Most recent log file:

```
2016-03-12T16:31:17.522-0500[API/1]OUTApp instance exited with guid 07407575-72e1-4bcf-9344-62c83d0d533e payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"07407575-72e1-4bcf-9344-62c83d0d533e", "version"=>"b98560f6-3880-41bf-b1b8-ccb372e093a4", "instance"=>"970f43d31dfb45ab81ac16ec4d6648fd", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1457818277}
2016-03-12T16:31:17.646-0500[API/1]OUTApp instance exited with guid 07407575-72e1-4bcf-9344-62c83d0d533e payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"07407575-72e1-4bcf-9344-62c83d0d533e", "version"=>"b98560f6-3880-41bf-b1b8-ccb372e093a4", "instance"=>"970f43d31dfb45ab81ac16ec4d6648fd", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1457818277}
2016-03-12T16:44:06.690-0500[DEA/103]OUTStarting app instance (index 0) with guid 07407575-72e1-4bcf-9344-62c83d0d533e
2016-03-12T16:44:19.047-0500[App/0]ERRError: Cannot find module 'extend'
2016-03-12T16:44:19.047-0500[App/0]ERR at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
2016-03-12T16:44:19.047-0500[App/0]ERR at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
2016-03-12T16:44:19.047-0500[App/0]ERR at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
2016-03-12T16:44:19.047-0500[App/0]ERR at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/node_modules copy/watson-developer-cloud/lib/index.js:22:20)
2016-03-12T16:44:19.047-0500[App/0]ERRmodule.js:328
2016-03-12T16:44:19.047-0500[App/0]ERR at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
2016-03-12T16:44:19.047-0500[App/0]ERR ^
2016-03-12T16:44:19.047-0500[App/0]ERR throw err;
2016-03-12T16:44:19.047-0500[App/0]ERR at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
2016-03-12T16:44:19.047-0500[App/0]ERR at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
2016-03-12T16:44:19.047-0500[App/0]ERR at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
2016-03-12T16:44:19.047-0500[App/0]ERR at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
2016-03-12T16:44:19.047-0500[App/0]ERR at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
2016-03-12T16:44:19.054-0500[App/0]OUT
2016-03-12T16:44:19.124-0500[DEA/103]ERRInstance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-03-12T16:44:19.152-0500[API/5]OUTApp instance exited with guid 07407575-72e1-4bcf-9344-62c83d0d533e payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"07407575-72e1-4bcf-9344-62c83d0d533e", "version"=>"b98560f6-3880-41bf-b1b8-ccb372e093a4", "instance"=>"5db58117c8a44c6992e4ba7005c33206", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1457819059}
2016-03-12T16:44:19.173-0500[API/1]OUTApp instance exited with guid 07407575-72e1-4bcf-9344-62c83d0d533e payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"07407575-72e1-4bcf-9344-62c83d0d533e", "version"=>"b98560f6-3880-41bf-b1b8-ccb372e093a4", "instance"=>"5db58117c8a44c6992e4ba7005c33206", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1457819059}
```

Forget what I said about node.js functions. I'm using visual recognition in this app and the file that was running without an error before didn't include all of my files. After pushing the rest of my project to bluemix I encountered the error in the log file above. The files I pushed were the node_modules necessary for visual recognition watson api as well as the api call which was made from app.js.

Comment: Can you please post your log files?

Comment: Is that what you meant?

Comment: Please provide the output of the command cf logs <appname> --recent

Comment: Please output the entire log using cf <appname> --recent

Comment: Your app is running and your log output contains no errors, so not sure how to help. https://crowd-counter.mybluemix.net

Comment: I'm just confused about the fact that the node.js functions aren't running on my application, am I supposed to edit something in the package.json or app.js file?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by 'the node.js functions aren't running on my application'. Your app that was running fine 4 hours ago is now gone and your log output contains no errors. You need replicate your error, provide the associated code and error output. Otherwise this is a hopeless endeavor

Comment: It seems that a required library is missing. Does the package.json contain the required dependencies? When installing via npm on your machine you could use "npm install <lib_name> --save". It updates the package.json in order to allow the buildpack to retrieve all the required libs.